# actually i have four type accesses are there i need count of all but inprogress is zero

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM vistors 
where typeofVistor='complaint' and 
access='open' or  access='inprogress' or access='onhold' or access='closed' and apartmentId=? 
group by access 
order by access desc
```

Comment: You should bracket the or block

Comment: please edit your post and add some information about your question and expectation.

Comment: 1) `access='open' or  access='inprogress' or access='onhold' or access='closed'` may be replaced with `access IN ('open','inprogress','onhold','closed')`. 2) The result makes no sense while NOT selecting `access` field - you'd not distinguish what count to what access is matched.